# how to get firestore data with firebase-admin when I use firebase emulators and next.js

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, next.js, firebase-admin

I use Next.js and firebase emulators.
I can add some data to firestore but I couldn't get data with firebase-admin.
how to get api data with firebase-admin.

```
// lib/firebaseAdmin.ts

const cert = {
  projectId: process.env.FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
  clientEmail: process.env.FIREBASE_CLIENT_EMAIL,
  privateKey: process.env.FIREBASE_PRIVATE_KEY.replace(/\\n/g, "\n"),
}

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(cert),
})

admin.firestore();
```

```
// api/foos/[id].tsx

import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next'
import 'lib/firebaseAdmin'
import { firestore } from 'firebase-admin'

export default async (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse<ResType>) => {
  const fooId = req.query.id as string
  const doc = await firestore().collection('foo').doc(fooId).get();
  const result = doc.id ? { id: doc.id, ...doc.data() } : {}
  
  res.status(200).json({
    foos: result
  })
}
```

Comment: If you are looking to run firebase-admin against the emulator you have to set the `FIRESTORE_EMULATOR_HOST` environment variable, and point it to the `host:port` address of the emulator.

Comment: @HiranyaJayathilaka 
I resolved this problem! thank you so much!

Comment: @HiranyaJayathilaka pls write this comment to answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To run `firebase-admin` against the emulator, set the `FIRESTORE_EMULATOR_HOST` environment variable, and point it to the `host:port` address of the emulator.